# Replace Leading zero with '+' in PHP

Tags: php

I want to replace the leading zero in a phone number with '+' and country code.

If the phone number starts with zero (ex: 07512345678) then I want to remove the leading zero and replace with '+' and country code else (ex: 7512345678)just add '+' and country code.

What would the way to do that in PHP?

Comment: I am new to php, I tried strpos,strrpos,preg_replace and also trim but I don't know what I did with my syntax. thats y I am asking help.@WebnetMobile.com

Comment: You didn't ask for help with your syntax…

Comment: I asked this only to know the efficient way in doing it since there are many ways @salathe

Comment: None of the answers below are *inefficient* at all, and the same is likely true for whatever you tried before.  So, now you have several efficient ways to play with.

Answer (score 13):

Use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
$newNumber = preg_replace('/^0?/', '+'.$countryCode, $phoneNumber);
```

The first parameter is the regular expression, which is looking for that leading zero of yours.  The second is what you want to replace it with (the plus sign concatenated with the country code.).  Finally, `$phoneNumber` is the original phone number.

The replaced value is assigned to the variable `$newNumber`.  Feel free to change the variables to fit your code.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`substr_replace()`](http://php.net/substr_replace), no need for regex or `if` blocks.

```
$number = '07512345678';
$country_code = '44';

$new_number = substr_replace($number, '+'.$country_code, 0, ($number[0] == '0'));
```

Comment: This is probably the most efficient, much better and less code than `if` blocks. `preg_replace` may rival it in performance however, interested to see preformance differences.

Comment: @Austin don't worry about the *preformance* [sic], this is presented as just another way of getting the job done.  A good `preg_replace()` is much easier in this case to read what the line of code is doing (see [SomeKittens' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12078629/113938).

Comment: http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/8913/newvz.png not me if that's what you are implying

Comment: Re. the down voter, due to the lack of any stated reason I am going to assume it is because he or she did not bask in the wonderment of a double rainbow today. That's a perfectly acceptable reason in my book; don't worry dear down voter, I won't take it personally. Better luck tomorrow. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `preg_replace`:

```
$newNumber = preg_replace("/^0/", "+", 07512345678)
```

This will replace the first character of each number if and only if it is zero. The regular expression used is: `/^0/`. The `^` tells it to look at the first character, and then only match a 0 thereafter. This 0 will be replaced with the second argument, the "+". The last argument is the source string.

**Reference**

- Take a look at `preg_replace` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)
- Basic syntax for beginning REGEX [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use string manipulation:

```
$x = '012345678';
if ($x[0]=='0') $x[0] = ''; // delete leading zero
$x = '+1'.$x;
```

Answer (score 0):

preg_match() is less effective I suspect, due to the complexity of the whole system.

```
<?php
$countryCode = "XX";
$phone = array("0123455", "7837373");
foreach( $phone AS $number ) {
   if( $number[0] == '0' ) {
      $number = "+{$countryCode}" . substr($number,1);
   }
   echo "{$number}\n";
}
```

PS: this is elementary. You should really got through some tutorials.